# How can I change the value of process.env.PORT in node.js? (Solved)

Tags: node.js, express

I've tried `set PORT=5000` with no success and `PORT=5000 node index.js` which throws the following error: 
"The term 'PORT=4444' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program."

I saw the same question resolved for Ubuntu, but I'm using Windows 10 (and VS Code console).

Thanks in advance!

**Edit: I found that running `$env:PORT=4444` in VS Code terminal works, no need to install additional modules in this case.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Common sense for this kind of configuration is to use `.env`-Files to configure your environments.

1. For this to work you would need the [dotenv-Module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv).
2. Create a File named `.env` in your app's root-folder and add your desired configuration like this:

```
PORT=5000
```

3. In your app you will have to call this at a very early stage.

```
require('dotenv').config()
```

4. You can then access your environment-variables in your code like this:

```
app.listen(process.env.PORT || '3000')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

1:

Install dotenv package:

```
npm i dotenv
```

2:

Create a .env file in the root directory of your project. Add environment-specific variables on new lines in the form of PORT=444. For example:

```
// If you want to change the PORT number just changed it from here.

PORT=4444
```

3:

```
require('dotenv').config()
```

By requiring this you are setting the PORT number from Process.env.PORT that you have recently assigned.

Or:

if you want to set your port number without using .env try this way:

In your index.js just set the port number for instance: `const port = 4444;`